# using es6 module exports in browser from HTML script

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, ecmascript-6, module

I am converting old javascript code to es6 modeules and am finding many issues because my old technique was to dynamically generate a lot of HTML tags which included hard-coded event handlers in the tags like this:

```
const html = '<input type="text" onclick="doThisOnClick();"/>';
getElementFromID('hostId').innerHTML = html;
```

Those handlers are in es6 modules and get cut out because there is no direct use of them in any scripts at load time nor are they called by other module code.
The only way to fix this I have found is to redesign my code to use dynamic event handler injection after generating the HTML tags.  This must be done asynchronouosly via a setTimeout() call.
I have been trying to discover other ways to make es6 modules accessible to potentially generated HTML code.
Here is a specific issue I am having:

```
<script type="module">
  import { deepFunctionUsedByPotentialEventHandler } from './bar.js';
</script>
```

The website is being hosted by nodejs:dev-server locally.
I get this error from chrome:

```
htmlFile.html:17 Uncaught SyntaxError: 
The requested module './bar.js' does not provide an export named 
'deepFunctionUsedByPotentialEventHandler ' (at htmlFile.html:17:10)
```

But the function is clearly exported in bar.js and is defined in bar.js:

```
bar.js...
function deepFunctionUsedByPotentialEventHandler() {
  ...
}

export { deepFunctionUsedByPotentialEventHandler, foo, bar };
```

I suspect that bacause there is no path to deepFunctionUsedByPotentialEventHandler at load time that the code has been stripped from the module for faster loading.
This is NOT using webpack or any other building type tool.

I would prefer to keep the global scope clean by not using window.deepFunctionUsedByPotentialEventHandler.

Seems to me that the ES6 spec should have a way to force keeping code available like:

```
export { foo keep, bar, bob }
```

I have tried a host of ideas but so far I have not found a quick-easy way to convert this code.

Comment: Would you be able to create a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? I was not able to reproduce it in this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-water-dsqjrc) (link may break in the future but here's the code: **index.html**: `<!DOCTYPE html><html><script type="module">import { foo } from "./index.js"; foo();</script></html>`; **index.js**: `console.log("index"); function foo() { console.log("foo"); } export { foo };`).

Comment: Here's an example, don't know codesandbox very well. index.html: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script type="module" import { onPageLoad, clickHandler } from "index.js"></script>
<body id="host" onload="onPageLoad();">
  <!-- dynamically created -->
</body>
</html> index.js: function onPageLoad() {
  const e = document.getElementById('host');
  e.innerHTML = '<button onclick="onClickHandler();">click me</button>';
}
function clickHandler() {
  alert('works!');
}
export { clickHandler, onPageLoad };

Comment: I still haven't been able to reproduce the issue you've described. I've been able to produce a different issue where `onPageLoad` isn't defined but that's only because it's in the scope of the script and not the global scope. Have you tried inspecting the response when you make the request to your JavaScript file? Is the response what you expect?

Comment: Yes, onPageLoad is broken.  If you try this change: <script type="module" import { onPageLoad, clickHandler } from "./index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  import onPageLoad from './index.js';
</script>
you get this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Comment: Right, that error is different from the one in your question? Regardless, you cannot reference things in a module in event handler HTML attributes because they're in a different scope. I would utilise [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to add your event handlers. For example: `import { onPageLoad } from "./index.js"'; document.getElementById("host").addEventListener("load", onPageLoad);`.

Comment: Exactly what I suspected was required.  I have now just about completed my conversion of my project to ES6 modules using AddEventListener methods.  It would seem that once you use modules there is no place for local HTML javascript anymore.  This makes sense in that modules are loaded in a delayed manner while most "text/javascript" references are loaded synchronously unless defered.  As long as I reference the addEventListener functions asynchronously after the HTML has been generated, all works well.  Thank you for your help.